# Bearer token using HttpURLConnection (Java 8)

Tags: java, java-8, bearer-token

Good afternoon,

I'm working on a project with 2 apps, the first one is a php app that provides me an API.
The second one is the app that I'm working on (Java 8 base, no Spring) My question is : Can I use the Bearer token authorization using the HttpURLConnection object ?

I'm still trying to make this work but it seems to make the value of "Authorization" null.

```
            //responseLogin is the token that the php app provides.
            String token = "Bearer " + responseLogin.toString();
            HttpURLConnection httpApi = (HttpURLConnection) apiUrl.openConnection();
            httpApi = (HttpURLConnection) apiUrl.openConnection();
            httpApi.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpApi.setDoOutput(true);
            httpApi.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            httpApi.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
            httpApi.setRequestProperty("Authorization", token);
            httpApi.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
            httpApi.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
            LOG.info("Token : " + httpApi.getRequestProperty("Authorization"));
            LOG.info("Accept : " + httpApi.getRequestProperty("Accept"));
```

httpApi.getRequestProperty("Authorization")); this part gets me a null response, I have no idea why.

I Hope anyone can help me with that, feel free to ask me if you need more information about my code.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a constant String array in HttpURLConnection that is called `EXCLUDE_HEADERS` and has the following comment:

```
// the following http request headers should NOT have their values
// returned for security reasons.
private static final String[] EXCLUDE_HEADERS = {
        "Proxy-Authorization",
        "Authorization"
};
```

The purpose is probably to not accidentally dump those headers, e.g. while logging the request.

**Note!** This doesn't mean they do not get set, just that they aren't being returned when you query for them. To test the actual values, one idea could be to use something like WireMock (or any custom server) to inspect what is actually sent.

Comment: Thank you so much. I suppose that my token works so, I'll run more tests to ensure that. The API returns something like that : 
`{"code":0,"message":"No matching routes"}`
I bet there is a problem with the link, I'll check with my coworkers. 
Thanks again, that was so helpful and made me learn something ! ;)

Comment: I am sending post request with bearer access token by using method request.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer" +token) but it returns error 401 unauthorized. The access token is auth2.0 and grant type is client credentials.